# SQL Injection Vulnerable script

Tags: php, sql

I've a strange question : I need to create a SQL vulnerable injection script ! The goal is that the script is vulnerable to Union based only !
Here is my script :

```
$req = "SELECT pseudo, mail FROM membres WHERE pseudo='".$_POST['membre']."'";
        $ans = $bdd->query($req);
        while($data = $ans->fetch()){
            echo '<p><b>'.$data['pseudo'].'</b> : '.$data['mail'].' '.$data['password'].'</p>';
        }
```

As you can see if you enter :

```
' UNION SELECT password, pseudo FROM membres#
```

The Script will output all the password of the db ! But this is not realistic ! My $data['password'] is all ready echo but empty by defalt !
How to make a proper vulnerable script wich allowed the hacker to list all table , all columns !
Because in my case only one or two payload will works !

Thank you

Comment: sql script is string based. all you need to do to make a second call is to terminate the current statement and append a ; before starting the next one. how can you limit the scope of what he injected script could do?

Comment: maybe: ' UNION SELECT pseudo, password As mail FROM membres#

Comment: Steve , can you explain more please ?